symmetry operation symbols
What does the symmetry operation symbols 3+ , 3- , $\overline{3}$+ , 3+1 , 3+2 indicate? Reference:- (1), (2) Without the superscript + or - symbol, it is easy to recognise that they indicate 3-fold rotational axis, 3-fold roto-inversion axis and 3-fold screw rotation respectively. If + and - indicates right and left rotation, why do these superscript symbols not used for all cases wherever rotational symmetry is mentioned, why for only few? For example, in P312, why doesn't 2-fold axis of rotation symbol carries + or - sign?   I'd appreciate if one could explain these along with tA (in Fddd) or tC (in C2/m).

For a twofold screw axis, it does not matter whether you rotate one or the other direction, the result is the same. For a threefold screw axis, it does matter.

These symbols are described in the International Tables for Crystallography A, chapter 1.4, in:
1.4.2. Descriptions of space-group symmetry operations
1.4.2.1. Symbols for symmetry operations

A rotation is symbolized by a number n = 2, 3, 4 or 6 (according to
the rotation angle 360°/n) and a superscript + or −, which specifies
the sense of rotation (n > 2). The symbol of rotation is
followed by the location of the rotation axis. Example: 4+ 0,y,0
indicates a rotation of 90° about the line 0, y, 0 that brings point
0, 0, 1 onto point 1, 0, 0, i.e. a counter-clockwise rotation (or
rotation in the mathematically positive sense) if viewed from point
0, 1, 0 to point 0, 0, 0.
A screw rotation is symbolized in the same way as a pure rotation,
but with the screw part added between parentheses. Example:
3- (0,0,1/3) 2/3,1/3,z indicates a clockwise rotation of
120° around the line 2/3, 1/3,z (or rotation in the mathematically
negative sense) if viewed from the point 2/3,1/3,1 towards 2/3,1/3,0,
combined with a translation of 1/3 c.

t stands for translation:

A translation is symbolized by the letter t followed by the components
of the translation vector between parentheses. Example:
t(1/2,1/2,0) represents a
translation by a vector 1/2 a + 1/2 b, i.e. a C centring.

Apparently, JKC's website uses tC for the same operator to denote that it's C centring. And tA for A centring.
